# mask oceans - wrld_simpl

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, r-maptools

I have been trying to colour the ocean in white or transparent in the code below, but have been unsuccessful so far. I have seen other posts on Stack but couldn't apply them to my example (e.g. [How can I color the ocean blue in a map of the US?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328438/how-can-i-color-the-ocean-blue-in-a-map-of-the-us)). I welcome suggestions. Thank you very much!

```
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
data("wrld_simpl")

#sample raster
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=20)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
extent(r) <- extent(c(-20, 20, -20, 20))

#plotting
var_df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$UN!="10",], 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               colour = "black", fill = "grey") # does the fortification automatically
p <- p + geom_raster(data = var_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer))
p <- p + coord_equal() +  theme_bw()  +labs(x="", y="") 
p <- p + theme(legend.key=element_blank(), 
               axis.text.y =element_text(size=16),
               axis.text.x =element_text(size=16),
               legend.text =element_text(size=12), 
               legend.title=element_text(size=12))
p <- p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(terrain.colors(10)))
p <- p + geom_polygon(data = wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$UN!="10",], 
                      aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                      colour = "black", fill = NA) 
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is that you want to show the raster over the land surface but not over the ocean. To do this it is easier to `mask` the raster by the land surface, I disaggregated the raster first to make the edges smoother:

```
#sample raster
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=20)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
extent(r) <- extent(c(-20, 20, -20, 20))

r=disaggregate(r,10)
r=mask(r,wrld_simpl)

#plotting
var_df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$UN!="10",], 
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               colour = "black", fill = "grey") # does the fortification automatically
p <- p + geom_raster(data = var_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer))
p <- p + coord_equal() +  theme_bw()  +labs(x="", y="") 
p <- p + theme(legend.key=element_blank(), 
               axis.text.y =element_text(size=16),
               axis.text.x =element_text(size=16),
               legend.text =element_text(size=12), 
               legend.title=element_text(size=12))
p <- p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(terrain.colors(10)))
p <- p + geom_polygon(data = wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$UN!="10",], 
                      aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                      colour = "black", fill = NA) 
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly! Thank you as well for the disaggregation suggestion